# Why wont this simple code work?

Tags: javascript

i have a simple js that wont work

I need to display the corresponding vaule for each var ie toy story 3 displays Comedy splendid choice and so forth

the problem seems to be in the if else syntax

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>help</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var movie = prompt("Select your favorite movie").toLowerCase();

if(movie =="toy story 3","kung fu Panda","RIO");
{
document.write("<p>Comedy splendid choice</p>")
}
else if(movie ="sex in the city","the backup plan","twilight");
{
document.write("<p>Chick flicks are always fun</p>")
}
else if(movie ="fast 5" || movie=="the karate kid");
{
document.write("<p>Action is satisfaction/p>")
}
else
{
document.write("<p>I’m sure it’s a good movie I just don’t know about it/p>")
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you get `movie =="toy story 3","kung fu Panda","RIO"` expression? You just thought "why not" and used random language construction expecting it to work?

Comment: I assume someone else will add this to their answer, but you should use `==` when comparing for equality, not `=` which is the assignment operator. As well as noting that the semicolon after the if statement's expression changes the meaning considerably.

Comment: And even more fun, you convert the input string to lowercase, but then compare to strings that have uppercase characters.

Comment: semicolons after the ifs.

Comment: There is so much wrong here I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove `;` in the end `if else` statement.

Second, use `||` to create or logical expression.

Third, you're lowercase your input, so compare your `movie` with lowercase literal too.

Fourth, use `==` when comparing for equality. `=` is used for variable assignment

Try this:

```
var movie = prompt("Select your favorite movie").toLowerCase();

if(movie =="toy story 3" || movie == "kung fu panda" || movie=="rio")
{
   document.write("<p>Comedy splendid choice</p>");
}
else if(movie =="sex in the city" || movie == "the backup plan" || movie == "twilight")
{
   document.write("<p>Chick flicks are always fun</p>");
}
else if(movie =="fast 5" || movie=="the karate kid")
{
   document.write("<p>Action is satisfaction/p>");
}
else
{
   document.write("<p>I’m sure it’s a good movie I just don’t know about it/p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an or:

```
if(movie =="toy story 3" || movie == "kung fu Panda" || movie == "RIO")
{
document.write("<p>Comedy splendid choice</p>")
}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "don't work"? Can you elaborate more?

If what you mean is nothing displayed, check your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var movie = prompt("Select your favorite movie").toLowerCase();

    if(movie =="toy story 3","kung fu Panda","RIO")
    {
        document.write("<p>Comedy splendid choice</p>");
    }
    else if(movie ="sex in the city","the backup plan","twilight")
    {
        document.write("<p>Chick flicks are always fun</p>");
    }
    else if(movie ="fast 5" || movie=="the karate kid")
    {
        document.write("<p>Action is satisfaction/p>");
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("<p>I’m sure it’s a good movie I just don’t know about it/p>");
    }
</script>
```

You miss-place the semi-colon (;). You should put semi-colon at the end of the statement, not after if case.

Should be:

```
if ( condition == true) 
{
    document.write("Hey, it's true!");
}
```

NOT:

```
if ( condition == true); // Semi-colon here means, it's the end of the statement
                         // the code after won't be executed
{
    document.write("Hey, it's true!"); // Semi-colon should be here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a switch statement instead of multiple if then elses...

```
switch(movie)
{
    case "Toy story":
        document.write("<p>Comedy splendid choice</p>");
        break;

    case "fast 5":
        document.write("<p>Action is satisfaction/p>");
        break;
}
```